# Why are tags related to themselves?

Tags: bug, related-tags

If you click on any tag, it opens up the main page for that tag. One of the options on that page is a link to the "top users" of that tag. If you follow that link you get various statistics relating to the top users of that tag. On the side of that page, though, is a list of "related tags". For some reason, the top related tag is always the tag itself. E.g. if you are on the "top users" page for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) the first tag displayed under "related tags" is [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

This seems a bit odd — the point of "related tags" is to show *other* similar tags, not the very tag that you are already viewing. Can this be fixed so that "related tags" only displays actual related tags and not the current tag itself?

Note, It is apparently only under the "top users" page the "synonyms" page, the "hot" page, and the "new" page that the tag itself appears as a related tag; on other pages that display related tags, such as the main page of a tag, the tag itself *does not* appear.

I checked various tags on various sites, and the issue appears to be the same on all of them. Here is a sample screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of related tags]